# Error uploading symbols for Parse Crash Reporting

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've got crash reporting working on my project, however symbol uploading is not working.

Couple things I've done:

1. Ensure current version of CLI is downloaded.
2. Verified path to cloud code is correct.
3. Attempted to manually upload the symbols (dSYM file)

I keep getting an error on the build script or when I manually upload:

```
The file "CrashReportingSymbols" couldn't be saved in the folder ".parse".

Uploading symbol files...

Uploaded symbol files.
```

When I open the crash in parse it says:

```
This stack trace is unsymbolicated. To obtain symbols, you need to upload your dSYM file via the command line tool.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Reported bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/587774604658221/